# ¿Como comprimir en unix todos los archivos .txt de diversos directorios en tar.gz?

Tags: unix

Estoy buscando la forma de comprimir solo archivos .txt en unix de diferentes directorios. Use el comando find para localizar los archivos .txt algo asi:

```
$ find ./ -name '*.txt' \+ |tar czvf comp.tar.gz ../
```

pero me comprime todo.

Comment: ¿Necesitas mantener la estructura de carpetas? Si es así prueba `find . -name "*.txt" -exec tar -rf comp.tar.gz {} \;`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, no, realmente busco solo encontrar los archivos .txt dentro de un directorio (que tiene mas directorior), de esta forma me ayuda a conservar cada directorio, en teoria me ayuda, jaja pero si busco solo encontrar los archivos con .txt intente algo como esto: $ find ./ -name '*.txt' -exec tar -zcvf comp.tar.gz {} \; pero solo me comprime el ultimo archivo  que encontro

Comment: `tar --transform 's/.*\///g' -zcvf comp.tar.gz */*/*/*/*.txt` prueba eso donde la cantidad de ` */` depende de la profundidad de tu directorio. La verdad es un problemilla que parece sencillo a primera vista pero se las trae jejej.

Comment: Lo otro que se me ocurre es copiar todos los `.txt` a una ubicación temporal y comprimirlos ahí. Eso no estaría mal.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jaime! Me ayudaste bastante, y la verdad es que si, jaja problemas sencillos derepente se vulven tediosos, mas cuando uno es nuevo, no se como marcarlo como resuelto si me lo pones en respuesta lo pongo como tal :D saludos!

Comment: Me alegra te haya ayudado. Ya agregué la respuesta. Quería asegurarme de que te había servido.

Comment: @SergioMijares Si te sirvió, por favor marca la respuesta como aceptada :) El tick junto a los votos de la respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar:

```
tar --transform 's/.*\///g' -zcvf comp.tar.gz */*/*/*/*.txt
```

Donde la sintaxis que recibe `--transform=` tiene la forma

```
--transform=s/[regexp]/[replace]/[flags]
```

Para este caso se transformaron todas las rutas remplazando (regex) `.*\/` al directorio raíz (replace) `/` de manera global (`g`) para todos los archivos coincidentes con el patrón.

Finalmente especificas el patrón que matcheará con los archivos que deseas poniendo tantos `*/` como profundidad tenga tu directorio.

---

De manera alternativa, combinado con `find` y ahorrándote contar la profundidad de tus directorios:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | tar --transform 's/.*\///g' -zcvf comp.tar.gz -T -
```

Comment: Respuestón. Siempre soy más amigo del pipe